# Работа Dictionary в совокупности с GameObject

Tags: c#, unity3d, словари

Для своей игры по типу "выберись из комнаты" хочу создать подсказки, появляющиеся при нажатии на кнопку с вопросительным знаком. Сама по себе подсказка представляет собой 3D объект (стрелку), указывающую на нужный элемент, эти 3D объекты уже есть на сцене, просто они отключены (на подобии SetActive(false) но через инспектор). Для отслеживания на каком игровом этапе находится игрок я использую bool флаги, переменные которые меняют своё значение именно в скриптах, с которыми я взаимодействую.

Пример:
Есть ложка и тарелка супа и ещё две стрелки одна показывает на ложку, вторая на тарелку супа. На ложке есть скрипт обрабатывающий клик, при нажатии ложка делается неактивной SetActive(false) и значение переменной bool меняется с true на false, при нажатии на тарелку супа скрипт висящий на супе обращается к объекту "ложка" и берёт оттуда значение переменной, проверяет чему она равно и через if скрипт решает можно ли использовать тарелку супа.

В итоге мне нужно: GameObject (ложка) на котором висит скрипт с переменной bool для отслеживания была ли взята ложка или нет, GameObject самой 3D стрелки, чтобы знать что активировать.

Я решил использовать Dictionary для того, чтобы в дальнейшем можно было пробегаться через for по всему списку, а не писать миллион if. В итоге столкнулся с двумя проблемами.

Мой Dictionary выглядит так (написал в void start, иначе выдаёт ошибку):

```
Dictionary<string, GameObject> dict_help = new Dictionary<string, GameObject>{
{"flag_lochka", GameObject.Find("Подсказка 1")},
{"flag_suup", GameObject.Find("Подсказка 2")}}
```

в итоге когда я пишу:

```
print(dict_help["flag_lochka"]);
```

Мне выдаёт:
Подсказка 1 (UnityEngine.GameObject)
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:print(Object)
Что как мне кажется хороший признак, но когда я делаю:

```
dict_help["flag_lochka"].SetActive(true);
```

Ничего не происходит, ошибок нет но и объект не включается. Это первая проблема, почему?

Вторая проблема заключается в том что я могу взаимодействовать со словарём только в start и не могу в других методах, например в "public void Helps()" говорит, что словаря с таким именем нет. Пытался решить эту проблему через public Dictionary<string, bool> dict_flag = new Dictionary<string, bool> но в таком случае он начинает ругаться на синтаксис до этой строки (на открывающуюся фигурную скобку от start и на весь следующий синтаксис идущий после на if скобки и т.д.)

Если интересна сама механика, т.е. зачем я хочу использовать Dictionary и как это будет работать, я создам 2 Dictionary первый с предметом на котором висит скрипт и второй Dictionary для предмета(стрелки с подсказкой) название словарей будут разными, но ключевые слова одинаковыми, таким обратом обращаюсь к двум разным словарям в цикле я смогу одновременно проверять какое значение имеет флаг bool и вместе с этим понимать какую подсказку нужно включить, так как ключевое слово одно и то же. Делать это буду через цикл и подсказка будет вылазит на первое значение флага bool, например если все флаги изначально true а после взаимодействия они становятся false то программа ищет в цикле слева на право первый флаг со значение true и выдаёт подсказку для него. такой метод хорош так как моя игра не является полностью линейной и некоторые действия можно выполнять в разном порядке. Следующая проблема с которой я столкнусь будет связанна с тем что название флагов и название самих скриптов откуда будут браться значение флагов будут разными значит, возможно, мне потребуется ещё два Dictionary с названием переменной и названием самого скрипта (ключевое слово будет тем же во всех случаях)

Comment: `Если вместо GameObject.Find использовать GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("3333") он не находит выключенный объект, но если его наоборот включить и в коде прописать чтобы он выключался, срабатывает. Выходит что в данном случае именно команда GameObject.Find работает не правильно.`, а потом пишите, что `Поэкспериментировал. Действительно, GameObject.Find ищет только активные объекты`. Я вас возможно удивлю, но этот метод работает абсолютно корректно. Просто он ТАК работает. Ищем только активные объекты. Об этот светло-серым по белому написано в документации: (прод. в след. коммент.)

Comment: В [документации](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html): `This function only returns active GameObjects`. Также ведет себя и [GameObject.FindWithTag()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindWithTag.html), и [GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет никакой специфичности в работе `Dictionary` в совокупности с `GameObject`.

Тут нужно вспомнить про области видимости.
Когда вы объявляете некоторую переменную внутри метода, то она будет видна только внутри метода. Что бы сделать нечто доступным внутри класса используются приватные поля класса. Что бы сделать что-то глобально доступным используются публичные поля класса (или свойства, но эта тема для другого вопроса). Таким образом в вашем случаи можно сделать так:

```
    private Dictionary<string, GameObject> dict_help; // объявляем пустой объект типа Dictionary<string, GameObject> с именем dict_help

    private void Start()
    {
        dict_help = new Dictionary<string, GameObject> // выполняем сложную инициализацию dict_help
        {
            {"flag_lochka", GameObject.Find("Подсказка 1")},
            {"flag_suup", GameObject.Find("Подсказка 2")}
        };
        //Дальше где угодно в классе можем спокойно использовать dict_help
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        dict_help["flag_lochka"].SetActive(true); //пример
    }
```

Если `dict_help["flag_lochka"].SetActive(true)` отрабатывает без ошибок, значит все правильно. У объекта с именем *Подсказка 1* должна изменится соответствующая галочка в инспекторе. Существуют ситуации, когда это не приведет к визуальным изменениям, например если объект *Подсказка 1* является дочерним объектом неактивного родителя.

Comment: Ваш ответ мне помог, я смог написать сроку dict_help["flag_lochka"].SetActive(true); в методе public void Helps() без получения ошибки, но, к сожалению команда по прежнему не срабатывает. Действительно у меня есть пустой объект в котором находятся все остальные подсказки, для удобной организации рабочего места, но родитель включен, я проверял, отключены только сами подсказки. Пробовал делать наоборот, выключать объект, так как ранее где то читал, что GameObject.Find может находить только активные объект , также не привело к результату. void Helps() точно выполняется, я писал там print

Comment: А если вы руками щелкаете на галочку слева от названия у объекта *Подсказка 1* он становится видимым?

Comment: Да, всё верно, становится видимым, это я проверял) Других объектов с таким же названием у меня нет в сцене, это точно

Comment: Кажется я нашёл решение данного вопроса, хотя и не понимаю почему это работает таким образом. Если вместо GameObject.Find использовать GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("3333") он не находит выключенный объект, но если его наоборот включить и в коде прописать чтобы он выключался, срабатывает. Выходит что в данном случае именно команда GameObject.Find работает не правильно. А для поиска выключенных объектов есть специальные методы, это я видел

Comment: Поэкспериментировал. Действительно, `GameObject.Find` ищет только активные объекты, но всё таки `dict_help["flag_lochka"].SetActive(true)` должны генерить ошибки в таком случаи. Вариант с изначально включенными объектами, которые потом отключаются в `start` вполне рабочий.

Comment: Если ответ был полезный, просьбы отметить его как верный (серая галочка рядом с ответом)

Comment: Я нашёл решение лучше, во всяком случае пока что кажется что оно лучше=)

public GameObject helpses; //родитель, в котором находятся подсказки

{"flag_lochka", helpses.transform.Find("Подсказка 1").gameObject}. И выключает и включает, без родителя так сделать не получится, так что если кто то когда то столкнётся с подобной проблемой и случайно попадёт на этот пост, вы знаете что делать =З

Только стоит отметить что не любой родитель подойдёт, говорят что только пустой объект, если записать подсказки в куб-не сработает, хотя не проверял